# Link Employee to User in API

Tags: acumatica

Using version 21.210.  I am able to create a user via the Contract-Based REST api and I am able to create an employee.  How can I link the employee to the user?  So, I want to do the equivalent of selecting a "Linked Entity" on the Users screen (SM201010).

I see a ContactID field in the Employee/ContactInfo entity but, it doesn't appear to be mapped to anything.  Also, it doesn't show on the entity when I query any employee using a GET and $Expand.  I'm thinking that I could use the ContactID from the Employee to plug into the "LinkedEntity" field on the User.

Any thoughts would be great.

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

It is linked by the UserID field on the Contact record(that is linked to the Employee via the Employee.DefContactID field). Users.ContactID is a virtual field but in the RowSelecting event it is populated by selecting a contact record where Contact.UserID is equal to Users.PKID.

So you would need to set the UserID field on the employee's Contact record to the user's PKID value. In addition there is also Employee.UserID that you would want to set equal to the Users.PKID value. The virtual field is populated using that Contact.UserID value but in the RowUpdating handler Acumatica is updating both the Contact and Employee records when Users.ContactID is changed.